# Custom Django Widgets/Fields: object has no attribute 'attrs'

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to make a custom form field in Django that allows a user to link a file or upload a file. To do this, I'm creating a subclass of the MultiValueField with the fields property set to (URLField(), FileField()). I'm not sure this is the right approach, but I keep getting an error I can't understand:

```
'MyFileField' object has no attribute 'attrs'
```

Here is my code. Can anyone explain what's going on?

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from .models import Case, Person, Opp, Category


class MyFileField(forms.MultiValueField):
    def compress(self, data_list):
        # I'll get to this once the attr error goes away
        pass

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = (
            forms.URLField(), forms.FileField()
        )
        super(MyFileField, self).__init__(fields=fields, *args, **kwargs)

class CaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Case
        fields = ['title', 'file', 'categories']
        widgets = {
            'file': MyFileField
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you define attrs in this line? `file': MyFileField` e.g `file': MyFileField(attrs={.....})`

Comment: When I do that I get the error: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling **init** on an abstract class.

```
 super(MyFileField, self).__init__(fields=fields, *args, **kwargs)
```

But the base class is abstract.

Look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#multivaluefield

and

[Python's super(), abstract base classes, and NotImplementedError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799401/pythons-super-abstract-base-classes-and-notimplementederror)

Comment: After reading through the above references, I'm still confused. In the Django documentation link you provided, the code example makes a call to `super()` in the same way that you suggest is the problem: `super(PhoneField, self).__init__(
            error_messages=error_messages, fields=fields,
            require_all_fields=False, *args, **kwargs))`