# python inhInheritance and Overriding __init__

Tags: python, abstract-class, init

i knon that a lot of people asked the same question, but i litte bit confused,
i have an abstract  class with `__init__`

```
class FirstTry(ABC):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        return NotImplemented
```

and a second class,

```
class SecondTry(FirstTry):
    def __init__(self, names: list, alias: dict) -> NoReturn:
        if names:
            self.names= names
        if alias:
            self.alies = alies
        self.names_count = None
        self.alias_alternatives = None
        super().__init__(names, alias)
```

but when i run my code i get this error

```
TypeError: FirstTry.__init__() takes 1 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: What do you *think* `super().__init__(names, alias)` does and why did you put that line of code in your program? Can you explain it?

Comment: i'm new, this line will take the suber init and redefine it with names and alias

Comment: Related: [Python's super(), abstract base classes, and NotImplementedError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4799401/2745495). Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4799574/2745495): "*If the method is abstract, the concrete subclass does not call super.*"

Comment: Note, you should not be doing `return NotImplemented`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the error is that this line:

```
super().__init__(names, alias)
```

is the same as calling:

```
FirstTry.__init__(self, names, alias)
```

and `FirstTry.__init__` only takes a `self` argument.

If you were going to call `FirstTry.__init__` via `super()` you'd want to call it in a way that matches its signature:

```
super().__init__()
```

but although this doesn't provoke a `TypeError`, it doesn't do anything useful -- in fact, if your `__init__` *raised* a `NotImplementedError` instead of *returning* it, you'd just get an uncaught exception.

It would be simpler to just not define or call `FirstTry.__init__` at all, since it's serving no function in this code.

Comment: but the FirstTry is a class shared by several classes that should have some functions

Comment: That doesn't mean that it needs an `__init__`.

Comment: how can i define the init in FirstTry and reuse it in all the classes

Comment: The way I described in my answer -- however, the implementation you showed doesn't do anything useful, so there's nothing to reuse.  There's no point having your child classes call an `__init__` function that doesn't initialize anything.

Comment: Note that you don't need to explicitly add a constructor for the sole purpose of calling the parent's constructor.  Regular old `object.__init__` will call `super().__init__()` for you.  (You *do* however need to explicitly call the parent's constructor *if* you override `__init__` for something else, since then that's getting run *instead of* `object.__init__`!)

Comment: @Samwise - I'm not sure I get what you're saying in your last comment.  Maybe you can elaborate a bit.  What is the first code block, and where do these things live in the class hierarchy?

Comment: @CryptoFool I have no idea what you're asking, sorry!  If you post it as a question with a code sample I'll take a look.  :)

Comment: Note, `NotImplemented` and `NotImplementedError` are two different things, and `NotImplemented` should not be involved here