# How to make a Python class properties accesible by index?

Tags: python, magic-methods, python-class, python-object

I have a Django model like this:

```py
class Competitor(models.Model):
  """
  Competitor model object
  """
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  easy = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Easy Mode')
  hard = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Hard Mode')
  tematicas = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=7, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Tematicas')
  random_score = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Random Mode')
  min1 = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='minuto 1')
  min2 = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='minuto 2')
  deluxe = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=14, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Deluxe')
  replica = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Replica')
```

And I want to be able to access the properties with index, therefore, if I write `competitor[0]`, it should return the value of `name`.

I have looked, and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359679/python-class-accessible-by-iterator-and-index) question, I have to "Implement both `__iter__()` and `__getitem__()` et alia methods." But I have no idea what to do inside this methods.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I want to thank @julianofischer for his answer. It taught me how to implement the methods I will implement in this answer.

First add a list of strings with the names of the fields you want to be able to access with `[]` as a propperty of the class, like this:

```py
class Competitor(Model):
  """
  Competitor model object
  """
  name = CharField(max_length=20)
  easy = ArrayField(PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Easy Mode')
  hard = ArrayField(PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Hard Mode')
  tematicas = ArrayField(PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=7, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Tematicas')
  random_score = ArrayField(PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Random Mode')
  min1 = ArrayField(PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='minuto 1')
  min2 = ArrayField(PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='minuto 2')
  deluxe = ArrayField(PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=14, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Deluxe')
  replica = ArrayField(PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Replica')
  _list = [ 'easy', 'hard', 'tematicas', 'random_score', 'min1', 'min2', 'deluxe', 'replica' ]
```

Then, if you want both to get and set the values, you have to implement `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, like this:

```py
def __getitem__(self, index: int):
  return self.__dict__[self._list[index]]

def __setitem__(self, index: int, value: list):
  self.__dict__[self._list[index]] = value
  self.save(update_fields=[self._list[index]])
```

This way, you are accesing the values of the fields with `__getitem__`, using `.__dict__[index]`, and returning those, and with `__setitem__`, you are modifying those directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning only to get items, you must override `__getitem__`.

```py
class Competitor(models.Model):
  """
  Competitor model object
  """
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  easy = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Easy Mode')
  hard = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Hard Mode')
  tematicas = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=7, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Tematicas')
  random_score = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Random Mode')
  min1 = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='minuto 1')
  min2 = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='minuto 2')
  deluxe = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=14, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Deluxe')
  replica = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Replica')

  def __getitem__(self, key):
      if key == 0:
          return self.nome
      elif key == 1:
          return self.easy
      ...
      elif key == 8:
          return self.replica
```

An easy way is to keep track of the properties using a list:

```py
class Competitor(models.Model):
  """
  Competitor model object
  """
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  easy = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Easy Mode')
  hard = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Hard Mode')
  tematicas = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=7, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Tematicas')
  random_score = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Random Mode')
  min1 = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='minuto 1')
  min2 = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='minuto 2')
  deluxe = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=14, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Deluxe')
  replica = ArrayField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(), size=9, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Replica')
  _list = [name, easy, hard, tematicas, random_score, min1, min2, deluxe, replica]

  def __getitem__(self, key):
      return self._list[key]
```

In order to fully implemented the subscript notation (`[]`), you will need to implement `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` too.

```py
  def __setitem__(self, index, value):
      self._list[index] = value
```

Comment: I am planning to get **and** modify items. So like `comp[0] = 'hello'`. If I want to do this, I have to implement `__setitem__`, right? If I have to, it is kindda intuitive how I should do it, but I want to make sure @julianofischer

Comment: I edited the answer and added a proposal of a __setitem__ method

Comment: It didn't work. There is no error, the value doesn't change. I noticed that if I do: `comp.__dict__['hard']`, I get `[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]`, but if I do `comp[2]`, I get `<django.contrib.postgres.fields.array.ArrayField: hard>` I guess that is why changing the value using `[]` doesn't work @julianofischer

Comment: sorry Joaquin, my mistake. 
check this:
`self._list[index] = value`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you could make this without mapping each index. Buf if you can ensure that the order of the indexes are going to always be the same, this works for you:

```
class Competitor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Leonardo'

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 0:
            return self.name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(Competitor()[0])  # Leonardo
```