# How to detect what element of a nested list has changed? (python)

Tags: python, list, class

I have a large 2D (list of lists) list, each element containing a list of ints, strings and dicts. I would like to be able to determine the 'path' (eg. [2][3][2]["items"][2] at the worst!) of any element that is modified, and have this fire upon modification. This list is to big to scan through and see what has changed!  Ideally, I also want a copy of the new element although this can be found out later.

My first attempt was to create a class, and override its `__setattr__` method:

```
class Notify():
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self.__dict__[name] = value       #Actually assign the value
        print name, value                 #This will tell us when it fires
```

However, the `__setattr__` method only fires when setting a variable that is not accessed by an index (or key), because this seems to outsource the call to the contained list()/dict() class not our class.

```
>>> test = Notify()
>>> test.var = 1          #This is detected
var 1

>>> test.var = [1,2,3]    #Now let's set it to a list
var [1, 2, 3]             

>>> test.var[0] = 12      #But when we assign a value via an index, it doesn't fire 
>>> test.var
[12, 2, 3]                #However it still assigns the value, so it must be talking to the list itself!
```

So, to summarise, I want (any method really) that tells me at what (list of indexes/keys) a change has occurred, and this needs to happen as it occurs because it is too expensive to scan through the whole list. I also can't rely on the code that modifies the list to provide the details. If this is not possible to the nth nested list, I could use something that only gave the first two indexes as the data there would not be too large to scan. Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT: Still no joy, though this question [Track changes to lists and dictionaries in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858525/track-changes-to-lists-and-dictionaries-in-python) seems to be close to what I need. Unfortunately, I'm not very good with classes and need the help of someone who is!

EDIT: Had a look at this [Python: Right way to extend list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196912/python-right-way-to-extend-list?rq=1) got me thinking that inheriting `list` might be a bad idea. I have come up with the following code using a proxy class instead. However the original problem remains, that modifications to nested lists don't log. Would class composition, not inheritance be a good idea?

```
from UserList import UserList

class NotifyList(UserList):

    def __init__(self, initlist=None):
        self.data = []
        if initlist is not None:
            if type(initlist) is list:
                self.data[:] = initlist
            elif isinstance(initlist, NotifyList):
                self.data[:] = initlist.data[:]
            else:
                self.data = list(initlist)

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        if type(item) is list:
            self.data[key] = NotifyList(item)
        else:
            self.data[key] = item
        print key, item

    def append(self, item):
        if type(item) is list:
            self.data.append(NotifyList(item))
        else:
            self.data.append(item)
        print self.index(item), item
```

Comment: maybe you could check in `__setattr__` the type of value, if it's a list you could wrap it inside a Notify object?

Comment: also, you could add some feature to Notify class such as a parent, so if a value is changed and the Notify class is not the root it could pass the event upward

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858525/track-changes-to-lists-and-dictionaries-in-python) answer may help you.

Comment: @lelloman I'm quite new to classes in python, but would new Notify class for new objects still act like like those objects (still have .append() for list ect.)?

Comment: @Mauro Baraldi thanks, this looks like what I need - how did I not find that!?

Comment: @Mauro Baraldi but will this work with nested lists that may contain dicts ect? Would it give a list of indexes/keys to the changed object or just the first one and a huge change?

Comment: I really don't know. Maybe if you test the code from answer you discover, and tell us if it works. :-)

Comment: I think the answer pointed out by @MauroBaraldi is what you need, but it's not very easy to understand if you are not familiar with OOP in python

Comment: still no joy guys, any actual working answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a reporting chain within your (trackable) list of trackable lists, where each list reports modifications to its parent. In your `NotifyList` class, add to the constructor an argument for the parent, and an argument for the ID by which the parent will know the new item -- when the parent is a list, this will be a list index:

```
class NotifyList(UserList):
    def __init__(self, inilist=None, parent=None, id=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.id = id
        # remainder of __init__()...
```

When a modification happens, the parent should be notified. For example in `__setitem__`:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, item):
    if type(item) is list:
        self.data[key] = NotifyList(item, self, str(key)) # Don't forget the new item's parent
    else:
        self.data[key] = item
    self.alertParent(str(key), str(item)) # Report up the chain instead of printing
```

`alertParent()` is:

```
def alertParent(self, key, item):
    strChange = "[{0}] = {1}".format(key, item)
    self.parent.notifyChange(self.id, strChange)
```

How does `notifyChange()` work?

```
def notifyChange(self, childKey, strChangeInChild):
    strChange = "[{0}]{1}".format(childKey, strChangeInChild)
    self.parent.notifyChange(self.id, strChange)
```

It just propagates the notification up the chain, adding its own ID to the message.

The only missing link is, what happens at the top of the reporting chain? The change message should finally be printed. Here is an easy trick to accomplish this by reusing `alertParent()`:

```
def alertParent(self, key, item):
    if self.parent is None: # I am the root
        print "[{0}]{1}".format(key, item)
    else:
        # remainder of alertParent() shown above...
...
def notifyChange(self, childKey, strChangeInChild):
    if self.parent is None: # I am the root
        self.alertParent(childKey, strChangeInChild) # Actually just prints a change msg
    else:
        # remainder of notifyChange() shown above...
```

I coded this up, the complete version is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3cAvQF-GRG3QXRqOFJyb2dJemc/view?usp=sharing) [Google Doc] (there are a couple of trivial bug fixes with respect to what I have presented above). In action:

```
>>> from test import NotifyList
>>> top = NotifyList([0]*3, None, None) # Now we have [0 0 0]
>>> print top
NList-[0, 0, 0]

>>> top[0] = NotifyList([0]*3, top, 0) # Now we have [ [0 0 0]  0  0 ]
[0] = NList-[0, 0, 0] #-------------- The tracking msg is fired

>>> print top
NList-[<test.NotifyList object at 0x0000000002163320>, 0, 0]

>>> top[0][1] = NotifyList([0]*3, top[0], 1) # Now we have [ [[0 0 0] 0 0]  0  0 ]
[0][1] = NList-[0, 0, 0] #----------- The tracking msg fired again

>>> top[0][1][2] = "this is a string" # Now we have [ [[0 0 "this is a string] 0 0]  0  0 ]
[0][1][2] = this is a string #------- And another tracking msg

>>> print top[0][1][2]
this is a string

>>> print top[0][1]
NList-[0, 0, 'this is a string']
```

Answer (score 0):

My [jsonfile](https://github.com/SzieberthAdam/jsonfile) module detects changes of (nested) JSON compatible Python objects. Just subclass `JSONFileRoot` to adapt change detection for your needs.

```
>>> import jsonfile
>>> class Notify(jsonfile.JSONFileRoot):
...   def on_change(self):
...     print(f'notify: {self.data}')
... 
>>> test = Notify()
>>> test.data = 1
notify: 1
>>> test.data = [1,2,3]
notify: [1, 2, 3]
>>> test.data[0] = 12
notify: [12, 2, 3]
>>> test.data[1] = {"a":"b"}
notify: [12, {'a': 'b'}, 3]
>>> test.data[1]["a"] = 20
notify: [12, {'a': 20}, 3]
```