# Using abstract base class VS plain inheritance

Tags: python, abstract-base-class

I'm trying to understand the benefits of using [abstract base classes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html).  Consider these two pieces of code:

Abstract base class:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod, abstractproperty

class CanFly:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def fly(self):
        pass

    @abstractproperty
    def speed(self):
        pass


class Bird(CanFly):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'flappy'

    @property
    def speed(self):
        return 1

    def fly(self):
        print('fly')


b = Bird()

print(isinstance(b, CanFly))  # True
print(issubclass(Bird, CanFly))  #  True
```

Plain inheritance:

```
class CanFly(object):

    def fly(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @property
    def speed(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()


class Bird(CanFly):

    @property
    def speed(self):
        return 1

    def fly(self):
        print('fly')


b = Bird()

print(isinstance(b, CanFly))  # True
print(issubclass(Bird, CanFly))  # True
```

As you see, both methods support inflection using `isinstance` and `issubclass`.

Now, one difference I know is that, if you try to instantiate a subclass of an abstract base class without overriding all abstract methods/properties, your program will fail loudly.  However, if you use plain inheritance with `NotImplementedError`, your code won't fail until you actually invoke the method/property in question.

Other than that, what makes using abstract base class different?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use Abstract Base Classes in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570796/why-use-abstract-base-classes-in-python)

Comment: @JayanthKoushik I don't think this question is a duplicate of that question, because this is asking about abstract base classes vs. plain inheritance, while the other question is asking about abstract base classes vs. duck typing.

Answer (score 12):

The most notable answer in terms of concrete specifics, besides what you mentioned in your question, is that the presence of the `@abstractmethod` or `@abstractproperty`<sup>1</sup> decorators, along with inheriting from `ABC` (or having the `ABCMeta` metaclass) prevents you from instantiating the object at all.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class AbsParent(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

AbsParent()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class AbsParent with abstract methods foo
```

However, there's more at play here. Abstract Base Classes were introduced to Python in [PEP 3119](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/). I'd recommend reading through the "Rationale" section for Guido's take on why they were introduced in the first place. My sophomoric summary would be that they're less about their concrete features and more about their philosophy. Their purpose is to signal to **external inspectors** that the object is inheriting from the ABC, and because it's inheriting from an ABC it will follow a good-faith agreement. This "good-faith agreement" is that the child object will follow the *intention* of the parent. The actual implementation of this agreement is left up to you, which is why it's a good-faith agreement, and not an explicit contract.

This primarily shows up through the lens of the `register()` method. Any class that has `ABCMeta` as its metaclass (or simply inherits from `ABC`) will have a `register()` method on it. By registering a class with an ABC you are signaling that it inherits from the ABC, even though it technically doesn't. This is where the good-faith agreement comes in.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class MyABC(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        """should return string 'foo'"""
        pass


class MyConcreteClass(object):
    def foo(self):
        return 'foo'

assert not isinstance(MyConcreteClass(), MyABC)
assert not issubclass(MyConcreteClass, MyABC)
```

While `MyConcreteClass`, at this point is unrelated to `MyABC`, it does implement the API of `MyABC` according to the requirements laid out in the comments. Now, if we register `MyConcreteClass` with `MyABC`, it will pass `isinstance` and `issubclass` checks.

```py
MyABC.register(MyConcreteClass)

assert isinstance(MyConcreteClass(), MyABC)
assert issubclass(MyConcreteClass, MyABC)
```

Again, this is where the "good-faith agreement" comes into play. You **do not have to follow the API laid out in `MyABC`**. By registering the concrete class with the ABC we are telling any external inspectors that we, the programmers, are adhering to the API we're supposed to.

<sup>1</sup> note that `@abstractproperty` is no longer preferred. Instead you should use:

```py
@property
@abstractmethod
def foo(self):
    pass
```