# What is the difference between Abstract Classes and Metaclasses in python?

Tags: python, abstract-class, metaclass

I read two articles about Metaclassing in python:

[What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)
http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/12/01/a-primer-on-python-metaclasses/

And I read about the ABC(abstract base classes) which is presented at:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html.

So I have to ask: What is the difference between a metaclass and abstract base classes (ABC)?

As I can understand I can use both to define class creation from metaclasses (**metaclass**).

For what purpose I would use an ABC or 'my own' metaclass?

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570796/why-use-abstract-base-classes-in-python

Comment: An ABC is an ordinary class (meaning, its instances are arbitrary objects), it's *an instance of* `type`. A metaclass has *other classes* for instances, and it *inherits from* `type` (in addition to being an instance of `type`).

Comment: @delnan I did not think you could create an instance of an abstract base class.