# No error while instantiating abstract class, even though abstract method is not implemented

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, abstract, abc

I was trying out the below python code:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Bar:

    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass


class Bar2(Bar):
    def foo2(self):
        print("Foo2")


b = Bar()
b2 = Bar2()
```

I thought having `@abstractmethod` will ensure that my parent class will be abstract and the child class would also be abstract as it is not implementing the abstract method. But here, I get  no error trying to instantiate both the classes.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: I did got exception `b=Bar() TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Bar with abstract methods foo`

Comment: @TanveerAlam Even I am surprised...I dont get the error...is it because of version? I am using 3.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must **set meta-class** of `Bar` class to `ABCMeta`.

Python 2:

```
class Bar:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass
```

Python 3:

```
class Bar(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Additionally, there must be at least one abstract method in order for the error to be raised, like in your examples.