# What is the best way to allow only one of a pair of arguments in a Python class constructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, constructor

I have a class which essentially functions like the example below. The constructor takes two arguments, which are both defaulted to `None` if no value is given. The goal of the class is that, given a value for `foo`, the user can call the `calculateBar()` function to calculate the value of `bar`. Conversely, the user should be able to provide a value for `bar` and then call the `calculateFoo()` function to calculate a value for `foo`. Notably, these functions are essentially the inverse of one another.

```
class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self, foo=None, bar=None):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar

        # Essentially an XNOR. Raises an exception if:
        # 1. Both foo and bar are 'None' (no value given for either)
        # 2. Neither foo, nor bar are 'None' (value given for both)
        if bool(foo == None) == bool(bar == None):
            raise ValueError("Please give a value for Foo or Bar (but not both)")

    def calculateFoo(self):
        return self.bar / 2.0

    def calculateBar(self):
        return self.foo * 2.0
```

The issue I have is that I want to restrict the class to only allow the user to give a value for `foo` OR a value for `bar`, but not both, i.e. exactly one of them should hold a value, the other should be `None`. My current method is to simply raise an exception in the case where either `foo=None and bar=None`, or `foo!=None and bar!=None`. This, however, seems like an inelegant solution. Is there a better way to restrict the user to entering just one of the two arguments, but still allow the correct use of the `calculateFoo()` and `calculateBar()` functions? Is there a better way to organise the class to allow what I need?

Comment: Why is this one class? If one type can only do foo things and the other bar things (foo can't calculate foo), then 2 classes may be a better solution. If they share some common functionality, then perhaps a shared base class for both?

Comment: If there's common functionality, you should just use parent and child classes though. So if both foo and bar can do baz things then create class `Baz` to do baz and then classes `Foo(Baz)` and `Bar(Baz)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you could split your class `ExampleClass` into two separate classes. At the moment your class is trying to do `foo` things and `bar` things but if one is not defined you leave the potential for an exception being raised because one member is not defined when calling `calculateFoo()` or `calculateBar()`.

What you could do is have an [abstract base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570796/why-use-abstract-base-classes-in-python) with a function `calculate()` and derive two separate classes `Foo` and `Bar` from this. Your derived classes will be forced to override the function. The abstract base class is purely a template - you will not be able to create an instance of it but it acts as a template for derived classes.

Example:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class BaseClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def calculate(self):
        pass

class Foo(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def calculate(self):
        return self.foo / 2.0

class Bar(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

    def calculate(self):
        return self.bar * 2.0


foo = Foo(10)
print(foo.calculate())

bar = Bar(10)
print(bar.calculate())
```

Output:

```
5.0
20.0
```

Comment: As suggested in your comment, there will be some common functionality here. I tried to make this as minimal as example as possible just to show off the problem. In reality my class takes a number of other arguments in its constructor and they are used (alongside some additional class member functions) in the respective calculations of `foo` and `bar`. My hope was that there was some straightforward way to have these both calculated using just the single class, but I think having a shared (abstract) base class may indeed be the way forward here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think your `__init__` is mostly fine, but make the check for both arguments *first*.

Once you've determined only one value was passed, set the other based on it.

```
class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self, foo=None, bar=None):
        if foo is not None and bar is not None:
            raise ValueError("Please give a value for Foo or Bar (but not both)")

        if foo is None:
            self.bar = bar
            self.foo = bar / 2.0
        else:
            self.foo = foo
            self.bar = foo * 2.0
```

An improvement would be to provide specific class methods for creating an instance for a single value, and discourage use of `ExampleClass.__new__` itself.

```
class ExampleClass:

    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar

    @classmethod
    def from_foo(cls, value):
        return cls(foo=value, bar=value/2)

    @classmethod
    def from_bar(cls, value):
        return cls(bar=value, foo=value*2)
```