# Abstraction in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, abstract-class, abstraction

I understand what abstraction is, however, I do not how we would implement abstraction in python. When searching, all I was able to find are abstract classes which I do not see relating to abstraction at all.

Comment: So, what's your question ?

Comment: maybe you can't find it because maybe nobody need it in Python.

Comment: @Maurice Meyer what is abstraction, and how do we implement it in python

Comment: @furas but dont universities teach you this stuff even if you wont ever use it?

Comment: at university I studied about abstraction in C++ and Java and they even have keyword `abstract` for this but Python doesn't have keyword `abstract` and probably nobody bother this.

Comment: Maybe this question answers yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570796/why-use-abstract-base-classes-in-python

Answer (score 2):

In Python, abstraction really only exists for design/conceptual purposes, not like in other languages like Java or C++.

Maybe you already saw `abc` module:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html